# Codeigniter - 404 Page Not Found

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, model-view-controller, http-status-code-404

I'm using Codeigniter. Everything is fine until when I'm create new controller named user_authentication.php (located on http://localhost/etalasekursusci/index.php/user_authentication). When I try to open this controller, the browser said "404 Page Not Found. The page you requested was not found". My controller files on http://localhost/etalasekursusci/index.php/controller and http://localhost/etalasekursusci/index.php/user work fine, just this one which fails.

**(FYI, I copy the user_authentication.php file from my friend. And if I copy the script inside user class to user_authentication class, the user_authentication.php can be accessed...)**

The /application/.htaccess file :

```
<IfModule authz_core_module>
    Require all denied
</IfModule>
<IfModule !authz_core_module>
    Deny from all
</IfModule>
```

The /application/config/config.php file :

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/etalasekursusci/';
```

The /application/config/routes.php file :

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'controller';
$route['404_override'] = '';
$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = FALSE;
```

The /application/controllers/user.php file (can be accessed):

```
<?php
class user extends CI_Controller {
public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();

    $this->load->model('user_model');
}

public function index()
{
    $this->load->library('form_validation');

    $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<div class="error">', '</div>');

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('nama', 'Nama Kursus', 'required|min_length[5]|max_length[20]');

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('alamat', 'Alamat Kursus', 'required|min_length[5]|max_length[40]');

    if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
    {
        $this->load->view('register_user');
    }
    else
    {
        $data = array(
        'lembaga' => $this->input->post('nama'),
        'alamat' => $this->input->post('alamat'),
        'paketkursus' => $this->input->post('paket'),
        'lokasi' => $this->input->post('lokasi'),
        'harga' => $this->input->post('biaya')
        );

        $this->user_model->insert_userinfo($data);

        $this->load->view('tambahberhasil');

    }
}
}
```

The /application/controllers/user_authentication.php file (which can't be accessed):

```
<?php
class user_authentication extends CI_Controller {

public function __construct() {
parent::__construct();


$this->load->helper('form');


$this->load->library('form_validation');


$this->load->library('session');


$this->load->model('login_database');

}


public function user_login_show() {
$this->load->view('login_form');
}

public function user_registration_show() {
$this->load->view('registration_form');
}

public function new_user_registration() {

$this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<div class="error">', '</div>');

$this->form_validation->set_rules('name', 'Name', 'required|min_length[5]|max_length[20]');

$this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'required|min_length[5]|max_length[40]');

$this->form_validation->set_rules('email_value', 'Email', 'required|min_length[2]|max_length[50]');

$this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'required|min_length[6]|max_length[10]');

if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
$this->load->view('registration_form');
} else {
$data = array(
'name' => $this->input->post('name'),
'user_name' => $this->input->post('username'),
'user_email' => $this->input->post('email_value'),
'user_password' => $this->input->post('password')
);
$result = $this->login_database->registration_insert($data) ;
if ($result == TRUE) {
$data['message_display'] = 'Registrasi Berhasil !';
$this->load->view('login_form', $data);
} else {
$data['message_display'] = 'Username yang ada inputkan sudah ada!';
$this->load->view('registration_form', $data);
}
}
}


public function user_login_process() {

$this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<div class="error">', '</div>');

$this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'required|min_length[5]|max_length[20]');

$this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'required|min_length[5]|max_length[40]');

if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
$this->load->view('login_form');
} else {
$data = array(
'username' => $this->input->post('username'),
'password' => $this->input->post('password')
);
$result = $this->login_database->login($data);
if($result == TRUE){
$sess_array = array(
'username' => $this->input->post('username')
);

$this->session->set_userdata('logged_in', $sess_array);
$result = $this->login_database->read_user_information($sess_array);
if($result != false){
$data = array(
'name' =>$result[0]->name,
'username' =>$result[0]->user_name,
'email' =>$result[0]->user_email,
'password' =>$result[0]->user_password
);
$this->load->view('admin_page', $data);
}
}else{
$data = array(
'error_message' => 'Nama atau Password yang anda masukan salah !'
);
$this->load->view('login_form', $data);
}
}
}


public function logout() {

$sess_array = array(
'username' => ''
);
$this->session->unset_userdata('logged_in', $sess_array);
$data['message_display'] = 'Anda sudah Log Out !';
$this->load->view('login_form', $data);
}

}
```

Any ideas?

**(FYI, I copy the user_authentication.php file from my friend. And if I copy the script inside user class to user_authentication class, the user_authentication.php can be accessed...)**

Comment: It looks like you need to configure your routes, check out the CI documentation (http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide2/general/routing.html)

Comment: post your `.htaccess` file that is in main folder `etalasekursusci` and what version of codeigniter are you using ?

Comment: Which version of Codeigniter are you using?

Comment: This question is asked lots of time.Did you searched at google?

Comment: There is no .htaccess file in my etalasekursusci main folder. I'm using Codeigniter version 3.0

Comment: by the way, if I copy the script inside user class to user_authentication class, the user_authentication.php can be accessed...

Comment: If you using CI3 your class name should start with upper case `User_authentication` and also file name should be upper case `User_authentication.php`

Answer (score 4):

In Codeigniter 3 your class names must start with an uppercase letter as should their filename.

You should try rename `user_authentication.php` to `User_authentication.php` and change the opening lines to:

```
<?php
class User_authentication extends CI_Controller {
```

similarly, the `user.php` should be changed to `User.php` and its opening lines to:

```
<?php
class User extends CI_Controller {
```

The class documentation explaining this can be found [here](http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/controllers.html#let-s-try-it-hello-world)

Answer (score 3):

Since you have defined base url as

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/etalasekursusci/';
```

Please try url  http://localhost/etalasekursusci/user_authentication without index.php

OR Define base_url in config as below with index.php

$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/etalasekursusci/index.php';

Please post controller code, If you can.

Comment: The base url should not have index.php appended on the end as per the documentation here: https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/url_helper.html  its purpose is to enable you to create links to static resources such as images or stylesheets.